# Using 74HC14 to invert a signal for HIN and LIN pin on IR2110

Tags: voltage, mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, tesla-coil

recently ive been working on a sstc solid state tesla coil project.I am using IR2110 gate driver ic for driving my IRFP450 N-channel mosfets in half-bridge configuration.so the IR2110 ic have two inputs which is the high side input(hin) and the low side input (lin),for the high and low side inputs i cant directly connect my oscillator circuit two both pins which will short the mosfets,so for that ive designed a simple circuit consist of an hex inverter ic
The 74HC14 hex inverter.
The signal from the oscillator circuit and the antenna goes to the pin 1 of the ic (1A) and in pin 2 (1Y)i should get a low output that i can connect to low side of the mosfet driver and pin 2 (1Y) will be connected to pin 3 (2A) thus the pin 4 (2Y) should theoratically output a high signal that i can connect to the high side of the mosfet driver ic

Long story short can i get the desired high and low signal via this circuit?

And finnaly,im running the entire setup with a total of 25v for the half bridge,12v for the gate driver ic and 5v for the logic side
The frequancy is roughly around 450khz with 60% duty cycle
[image]

Edit:for some reason i cant post any comments,so im really sorry if not not replying im having some problems
And i will do some research and try every circuits that you guys provide,im really sorry

Comment: There will be a propagation delay between the outputs of 1Y and 2Y meaning that both outputs will be high for a short period of time. For the 74HC14 this will around 10ns. If your circuit can tolerate this you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this IR App note AN-978:

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626c1f3dc3016c47de609d140a&redirId=114085

It has a couple things to say about deadtime...

In Section 2.1:

> Those applications that require a minimum deadtime should use MGDs with integrated deadtime (half-bridge driver) or a high- and low-side driver in combination with passive components to provide the needed deadtime, as shown in Section 12.

and in Section 12:

> The turn-on and turn-off propagation delays of the IR2110 are closely matched (worst case mismatch: 10 ns), with the turn-on propagation delay 25 ns longer than the turn-off. This, by itself, should insure that no conduction overlap of the power devices would occur, even if the on and off input command coincide.

Since the propagation delay of the 74HC14 is around 10ns, this should leave around a 15ns of deadtime. Perhaps others can comment on whether this is enough of a margin.

**Update:** Here are a couple of inverter designs using the IR2110 I was able to find.

This one uses a 2n3904 inverter to provide the complimentary HIN and LIN signals.

https://www.instructables.com/Gate-Driver-Circuit-for-Three-Phase-Inverter/

And this one bit-bangs the HIN and LIN pins using a microcontroller (Arduino) inserting a 1 us delay before bringing any signal high:

http://vadic.vigyanashram.blog/2020/12/17/solar-based-micro-inverter/